# firebase user is logged out everytime browser refreshes with development

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hello I am trying to figure out why in firebase in the development stages of my application when I make changes in the front end that my app redirects to the login page without me logging out intentionally, I want to keep persistence but when I try doing the persistence method in the documentation in the firebase website I get errors on **persistence** and **Auth**  not being defined. I do not want the changes I make in the development to be refreshed to the point I have to login again here is my code on the firebase persistence authentication

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
  .then(function() {
    return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  })
```

The main goal that I want is to be able to make changes in my development without my user being logged out whenever my browser refreshes and redirecting to my login page